# Error while connecting to Outlook inbox through EWS

Tags: java, outlook

Before posting here, I have gone through similar posts but could not find solution. I am trying to read my Outlook inbox using EWS API but i keep getting 401 access denied error. Please help me.

I have set the user name, password and domain as per the API need, but don't know why it shows 401.

```
public final class ExchangeServerConnection {

    private static String exchangemailurl;

    private static String userName;

    //private static String password;
    private ExchangeServerConnection() {

    }


    public static ExchangeService connectionEWS(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        {
            ExchangeService service = null;
            try {
                service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
                ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username@comp.com", "Uddsa#2k16", null);
                service.setCredentials(credentials);
                service.setUrl(new URI("https://email-domain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx"));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            }
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class EmailUtil {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

        ExchangeService service = ExchangeServerConnection.connectionEWS("Uaua#2k16");
        System.err.println("Connections has been set up");
        FolderView view1 = new FolderView(EWSConstants.TEN.getNumber());
        System.err.println("1");
        //  ExtendedPropertyDefinition isHiddenProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(EWSConstants.PRODDEF.getNumber(),
        //  MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
        System.err.println("2");
        //PropertySet pr1 = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName, isHiddenProp);
        // view1.setPropertySet(pr1);
        System.err.println("3");
        view1.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);
        System.err.println("4");
        SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, EWSConstants.INBOX.getValue());
        System.err.println("5");

        searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilter1);
        System.err.println("6");
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, searchFilter1, view1);
        System.err.println("7");
        Folder folder = findFolderResults.getFolders().get(0);
        System.err.println("8");
        folder.load();
        System.err.println(folder.getTotalCount());
        int messageCount = folder.getTotalCount();
        System.err.println("message count is "+messageCount);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the credentials properly formed?  It looks like you are trying to connect with an email address rather that a user / domain pair.  Does it help to change

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = 
    new WebCredentials("username@comp.com", "*pass*", null);
```

to

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = 
    new WebCredentials("username", "*pass*", "comp.com");
```

or

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = 
    new WebCredentials("username", "*pass*", "*name.of.domain.the.exchange.server.is.on*");
```

Comment: `  ExchangeCredentials credentials = 
         new WebCredentials("Murali.S", "pass", "host.comp.com");`

But it still throws the same error